# How to remove children of children in data frame to plot network in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to plot a network with R. The problem, however, is that my data frame, which contains the relationship data, also contains children of children. It looks like the following:

```
parent <- c("A","A","A","B","B","E")
child <-  c("B","C","D","C","D","D")
df <- data.frame(parent,child)
```

I would like to remove the children of children in `df` so that I can use igraph to plot my network. So basically, I want my data to look like `df_net`:

```
parent <- c("A","B","B","E")
child <-  c("B","C","D","D")
df_net <- data.frame(parent,child)
```

```
net <- graph_from_data_frame(df_net,directed = T)
plot(net)
```

[Figure of plot(net)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn7jj.png)

What is the best way to (automatically) remove the unnecessary rows of `df`? (I have several data frames with up to 100 rows - removing the rows by hand is therefore not an option.)

My first idea was to use a while loop to find the parents in each hierarchical step. I thought I could us this to filter the rows in `df`. But I don't think I'm on the right track here. Any ideas are appreciated!

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
i <- nrow(df)
y <- list()
z <- list()
j <- 1
while (i > 0) {
  v <- unique(df$parent[!(df$parent %in% df$child)]) # find mismatch (only in parent, not in child)
  df <- df %>% filter(parent %notin% v)
  print(v)
  y[[j]] <- v
  z[[j]] <- df
  i = nrow(df)
  j = j+1
}
```

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to keep all items in parent that are not in child?

Comment: No, the last part was just an idea that did not work out in the end. I want to delete rows from df that are not directly related. For instance, keep the first row (A B) but remove the second (AC) and third (AD) because A is not directly related to C and D but only via B.

Comment: Because B (that is a children of A) has also C and D as children. It is a precondition of the hierarchical model that A is therefore not directly related to C and D.

Answer (score 1):

How about using igraph to determine the paths between individuals, and if there are more than 1, remove that connection?

```
library(igraph)
parent <- c("A","A","A","B","B","E")
child <-  c("B","C","D","C","D","D")
df <- data.frame(parent,child)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(df,directed = T)
df <- df[apply(df,1,function(x){length(all_simple_paths(net,x[1],x[2]))}) == 1,]
df
  parent child
1      A     B
4      B     C
5      B     D
6      E     D
```

I fear this may be pretty slow on extremely large graphs, so if anyone has a data.table solution, that might be better.

Comment: Would be cool if it was that simple! However, I got an error message:  "Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, from) : Invalid vertex names" :(

Comment: Sorry, I left out an important step.

Comment: Thank you!!! That works perfectly! I would have never thought of that. I tried with some of my data and it was not slow at all. So for me, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# get data
parent <- c("A","A","A","B","B","E")
child <-  c("B","C","D","C","D","D")
df <- data.frame(parent,child, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# remove rows that are not directly related
new_df <- anti_join(df,
          left_join(df,df,by=c("child"="parent")) %>% 
  select(parent,child=child.y) %>% 
  na.omit()) 

new_df
  parent child
1      A     B
2      B     C
3      B     D
4      E     D
```